How do I create a token metadata account?
I would like to create a metadata account to update the metadata.
//Connection and Umi instance
const endpoint = clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta");
const umi = createUmi(endpoint);
const connection = new Connection(endpoint);
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(secret));

//Constants
const mplProgramId = new PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");
const mint = new PublicKey("Hd65ZzpmXaXgmjRy7QrVPmSqiWzZDRFkLCTBfoBM6XAz");
const [metadata] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([
    Buffer.from("metadata"),
    mplProgramId.toBytes(),
    mint.toBytes()
], mplProgramId);

//Metadata Account IX Args
const args = {
    data: {
        name: "FIG Token",
        symbol: "FIG",
        uri: "https://e2tqckikfjrzclhuy3cfvphueud4ztbh55v7nys6vtfgmd2vri2a.arweave.net/JqcBKQoqY5Es9MbEWrz0JQfMzCfva_biXqzKZg9VijQ",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
        collection: null,
        creators: [
            { address: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(keypair.publicKey), verified: true, share: 100 }
        ],
        uses: null
    },
    isMutable: true,
    collectionDetails: null
};

//The tx builder expects the type of mint authority and signer to be Signer, so built a dummy Signer instance
const signer = {
    publicKey: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(keypair.publicKey),
    signTransaction: null,
    signMessage: null,
    signAllTransactions: null
};

//Metadata account IX Accounts
const accounts = {
    metadata: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(metadata),
    mint: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(mint), 
    payer: signer,
    mintAuthority: signer,
    updateAuthority: fromWeb3JsPublicKey(keypair.publicKey)
};

//Arguments merged to match the parameter required by the method
const fullArgs = { ...accounts, ...args };

const metadataBuilder = createMetadataAccountV3(umi, fullArgs);

(async() => {
    const ix = metadataBuilder.getInstructions()[0];
    ix.keys = ix.keys.map(key => {
        const newKey = { ...key };
        newKey.pubkey = toWeb3JsPublicKey(key.pubkey);
        return newKey;
    });

    const tx = new Transaction().add(ix);
    const sig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, tx, [keypair]);

    console.log(sig);
})();


Error Logs
  logs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: IX: Create Metadata Accounts v3',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program log: Mint authority provided does not match the authority on the mint',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 10679 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: custom program error: 0xa'
  ]

Mint Address : Hd65ZzpmXaXgmjRy7QrVPmSqiWzZDRFkLCTBfoBM6XAz#metadata
mintAuthority Address : 68bskZB1L5Vz8MW7xt2Y6Sq3ugKz59QQEXZSmNNxCxBV
"Mint authority provided does not match the authority on the mint"
I don't understand this.
I made it through spl-token cli when I made the token and it's the same wallet I used at that time.
Is this method wrong or is there a way to know the authority of mint?

The error is clear in this case, but hopefully it'll be an easy fix -- double-check that the mint authority stored in the mint matches keypair.publicKey.

@JonC Thanks for your answer.
I disabled mintAuthority a long time ago.
I think that's why the error occurred.
Can I set a new mintAuthority for this token?
tx:
2AphGmZv7Mo83Pwk1L89KjEPXMHUwwb9cpYJ2sMvs7XreJE6eZy1hL1M83Uz4ezTb6qJ8RPzZ2vjKADvbUubrP52

If you've relinquished mint authority, it's not possible to add it back unfortunately
